# ipynb file does not open anymore

Tags: python

I was working on a ipynb in pycharm. And suddenly I'm not able anymore to open that file. I can see raw code with a text editor like sublime and pasting it in online validator I get this error. How can I find a solution? I'm worried that I've lost everythng.
[image]

[image]